#  Using reflection to get a property of a property of an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Lets say I have a LunchBox class with a property for FreezerPack that has a property for Name.

```
public class LunchBox
{
    public FreezerPack FreezerPack { get; set; }
}

public class FreezerPack
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection, I can get FreezerPack like so:

```
var lunchBox = new LunchBox
{
    FreezerPack = new FreezerPack
    {
        Name = "I'm so cool"
    }
};

var freezerPack = typeof(LunchBox)
                    .GetProperty("FreezerPack")
                    .GetValue(lunchBox, null);
```

But how can I get Name from FreezerPack in LunchBox when all I have is LunchBox as T and a string with the property path "FreezerPack.Name"? `.GetProperty("FreezerPack.Name")` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to reflect on the result of the `FreezerPack`:

```
var lunchBox = new LunchBox() { FreezerPack = new FreezerPack() { Name = "I'm so cool" } };
var freezerPack = typeof(LunchBox).GetProperty("FreezerPack").GetValue(lunchBox, null);
var freezerPackName = freezerPack.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(freezerPack, null);
Console.WriteLine(freezerPackName);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, but it looks like this is the way the cookie crumbles.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic` might make sense in this case:

```
dynamic lunchBox = new LunchBox() { FreezerPack = new FreezerPack() { Name = "I'm so cool" } };
string name = lunchBox.FreezerPack.Name;
```

Comment: I (think) this is just a contrived example. If you take the example literally, there is no need for dynamic or reflection since we could just access the type / properties statically.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a contrived example.  I don't know enough to know whether dynamic or reflection is the right approach, so I just thought I'd suggest dynamic.